# Wix HTML code - linking to a document

Tags: html, velo

Inserting HTML code into my wix site so I can use an accordion. I want to create links to documents I've uploaded to wix.

Have tried

```
<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/documentname.pdf">doucment</a>
<br>
<a href="/documentname.pdf">document</a>
```

Can't figure out how. Sorry if this is really easy, no where else to ask.

Comment: No space at the beginning.

Comment: I put the space there so you could see the code

Comment: Fixed it for you.  Your problem lies elsewhere then.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/document.pdf" download>
  download pdf
</a>
```

Here "download pdf" the text you want to show.

Comment: Problem is the documents are stored by wix so they aren't mysite.com/something.

Comment: In that case you should use the url of the website its stored on. So that could be https://www.externalwebsite.com/document.pdf